Cefsharp based browser access denied don't have permission to access on this server
I built my web browser using CefsharpV110.When it visited some websites,the following errors appeared:

Access Denied
You don't have permission to access on this server
Reference #18.62a7cb17.1722934900.6e45092c
https://errors.edgesuite.net/18.62a7cb17.1722934900.6e45092c

In the same machine ,I tried to visit the same website using chrome and it worked fine. So I am sure there is nothing about the network,So how to fix it?
My code is below
    Dim settings As New CefSettings()
    settings.PersistSessionCookies = True
    settings.CachePath = CurDir() + "\cookie"


    settings.Locale = "zh-CN"
    settings.AcceptLanguageList = "zh-CN,zh;q=0.9"
    Dim browserSettings = New BrowserSettings()
    browserSettings.AcceptLanguageList = "zh-CN,zh;q=0.9"

    Dim flashPath = "pepflashplayer32_29_0_0_171.dll"
    settings.CefCommandLineArgs("enable-system-flash") = "1"
    settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("ppapi-flash-version", "21.0.0.182")
    settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-media-stream", "")


    CefSharp.Cef.Initialize(settings)
    CefSharp.Cef.EnableHighDPISupport()

    chromeBrowser = New ChromiumWebBrowser("https://www.coachoutlet.com/wishlist")
    chromeBrowser.RequestHandler = New checkframe()
    chromeBrowser.Size = New Size(600, 600)
    chromeBrowser.Location = New Point(700, 150)
    chromeBrowser.BrowserSettings = browserSettings
    Me.Controls.Add(chromeBrowser)
    chromeBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Left
    chromeBrowser.BringToFront()
    chromeBrowser.Visible = True


Version 110 is old and unsupported. Try the current supported version. For testing purposes you can try https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample
